# I made some changes in a container's volume. Do I need to rebuild my whole docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-volume

I want to understand, when do i need to rebuild my whole docker-compose? Does any changes in the volume in a specific container need to rebuild the whole docker-compose?
How can I know which changes requires to rebuild/restart the whole docker-compose?

Comment: if you have changed in the files then you need to use docker compose again but changes in docker volume don't need rebuild as it is separate

Comment: If your program wasn't running in Docker, when would you need to restart or rebuild it?

Comment: @DavidMaze the program ran in Docker, but i want to know if i need to rebuild the Docker or it's enough to run the Docker.

Comment: @devforhelp Thank you for your answer. Can you explain why?

Comment: for development no but for production yes and you can check this link for more info https://vsupalov.com/rebuilding-docker-image-development/